# Why doesn't ParentView.Width get me the ParentView's Width in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It's really this simple. I want the Width of my entire screen in Xamarin.Forms. You'd think that when I call `ParentView.Width`, it will return for me the width of the parent view. Instead, it returns me an exception. "Object reference not an instance of an object."

What do I do to get the Width of a parent view so that I can manipulate a child element based on that width. For instance:

```
int xPos = this.Width*0.5;
//or 
int xPos = ParentView.Width*0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the width of the screen, you can use

on Android:

Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels

or (more likely):

```
Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / 
            Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density
```

if you want it in dip and not in pixels.
(all Xamarin.Forms controls use dip for their WidthRequest and HeightRequest).

on iOS:

```
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width
```

You can also make an interface and use DependencyService to return the width for each platform to your shared project

Comment: You could also find working implementation in Xamarin-Forms-Labs project https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Device (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26504582/5064986)