# How to add two full-sized page in scrollview(vertical) on Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app using with Xamarin.forms.
What I'm doing is really hard. Can't figure out so far.

I want to add two view(or page) into scrollview(vertical) and size of each view is equal with screen size. So If I scroll down, second view show up and first view will be hidden.

How to make it with using xaml?

I tried stacklayout, grid, relative, absolute. 
Nothing works. (I believe there is some way to do it)

Thanks.

Comment: Use a ScrollView containing a StackLayout containing two ContentView, each sized to fill the screen

Comment: @Jason Hi, I tried it and really hope that would work but it's not working. It just create two contentView half size of screen.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Carousel View instead of a scrollview. 
Check this link http://chrisriesgo.com/xamarin-forms-carousel-view-recipe/

Comment: @BraveHeart Thanks. That's interesting approach.
But there is no vertical CarouselPage? That's what I need.

Comment: @BraveHeart hmm.. That link you gave me might help to make vertical CarouselPage. I will try it.

Comment: Note that you need Carousel View , not Page :)

Comment: @BraveHeart Yes I know. I tried using Chris's code to make vertical Carousel View but it's not working. I'll request that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I used for this was, to create a `StackLayout` with vertical orientation inside a `ScrollView`. Inside it I have a two `StackLayout`.

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
        <StackLayout x:Name="FirstStack" BackgroundColor="Red">
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="SecondStack" BackgroundColor="Blue">
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

After this I setted programmatically the `Height` for each page.

To get the screen `Height` i did it the simpler way (just to test it) but you should do it in a [better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465513/how-to-get-detect-screen-size-in-xamarin-forms).

On iOS inside `FinishedLaunching`:

```cs
App.ScreenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

On Android inside `MainActivity` (*need to be tweaked + 0.07f*):

```cs
App.ScreenHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / (Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density + 0.07f));
```

In you `Application`:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static int ScreenHeight;
```

And finally in the `Page`:

```cs
public ScrollVerticalPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FirstStack.HeightRequest = App.ScreenHeight;
    SecondStack.HeightRequest = App.ScreenHeight;
}
```

Final result [here](https://sendvid.com/b0dlpm2c).

Comment: Thanks again @jzeferino . It's right and good approach. I really appreciate.

Comment: On Android its not perfect but its a matter of testing a bit more and try to relate the conversion of Android pixels and xforms size. Thank you.