# How to get points or pixels per inch of device using xamarin.iOS project?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The question is simply as stated in the title:

How is it possible to find out the pixel or point density (per inch) of a screen's device in **Xamarin.iOS** project?

I have found a few "solutions" like [the one stated by @JohnHardman in a post in Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/346218#Comment_346218) (which happens to use the code from **XLabs** also suggested in [an answer by @SKall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465513/how-to-get-detect-screen-size-in-xamarin-forms) in another SO thread, and as stated in the forum i could not use since it is "likely" to cause a rejection in the **Apple store**).

Other solution seems to be by using the wonderful **Xamarin.Essentials**. Nevertheless, they return only *High*,*Width* and *Scale*. But scale is not what i am looking for...

So, does anyone know a way on this seemingly easy/trivial path? (why should it be so complicated such a basic task?)

Comment: What do you want to do ? Whether you want to determine the device model by getting the screen width and height？

Comment: Hi @LucasZ, actually i want to get the device's screen diagonal measure in inches to determine if the device is smaller or bigger that a "critical" measure i define...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read directly the method i used to finally obtain pixel density please read below the "**My final method**" section. If you want to read how i came to it keep reading.

---

So, i did further research and i came to a solution that satisfies me. I will share it here for the posterity.

First of all, [i was told by @ColeX](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/346597/#Comment_346597) (a member of the **Xamarin** Team) that

> There is no public API for getting points or pixels per inch of device
>   in iOS.

So a different approach is required. First i thought i could get the screen size by Switch-Casing the size in pixeles, which is obtainable in the public API, but as i wrote in a comment above to @LucasZ this would be imprecise since

> iPad mini and iPad Air: they both have the same height (1024) and the same scale (2x), but since the PPI are different it turns out that they are 7.9 in and 9.7 in respectively...

Then there was the option with the code from **XLabs** that i mentioned above. This method i found first in [a thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/298105/#Comment_298105) in the **Xamarin Forums**, and then independently in [a library of **XLabs**](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs). This had nevertheless the drawback of the comment about violating the Apple guidelines...

Happily, after further research and more Q&A, in **Xamarin Forums** in [another thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/346711/#Comment_346711) i was pointed by @LandLu (also a member of the **Xamarin** Team) to yet [another library](https://github.com/dannycabrera/Get-iOS-Model): this library also makes the mysterious query to `hw.machine`. So i decided to ask the author about the risk of using such method and [he answered](https://github.com/dannycabrera/Get-iOS-Model/issues/12#issuecomment-420864142):

> Hi @deczaloth,
>
> It shouldn't be a problem as Apple checks every app upon submission to see what API calls are made and retrieving the hardware string hasn't been a violation. There are other calls I have seen rejected but not hw.machine. Hope that answers your concern. Regards

---

**My final method was:**

1. Get the detailed iOS Model by retrieving the hardware string using [a special library/nuGet/code](https://github.com/dannycabrera/Get-iOS-Model) (or refer to the code in the **APENDIX**).
2. Switch-Case the detailed model obtained in the previous step with the public information about screen sizes in inches (this information is public and there are many sources, for example the infamous [iosres.com](http://iosres.com/)).
3. Use the public API (`UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size`) to get the screen diagonal size in pixels (basic Pythagorean mathematics) and with this calculate the pixel density: `pixels per inch = diagonal-size-in-pixels/diagonal-size-in-inches`.
4. Voila!

---

**APENDIX**

Code to retrieve hardware string:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ObjCRuntime;

public static string GetiOSModel() =>
    GetSystemProperty(string property);

public static string GetSystemProperty(string property)
{
    var pLen = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
    sysctlbyname(property, IntPtr.Zero, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    var length = Marshal.ReadInt32(pLen);
    var pStr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
    sysctlbyname(property, pStr, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pStr);
}

/// <summary>
/// Sysctlbynames the specified property.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="property">The property.</param>
/// <param name="output">The output.</param>
/// <param name="oldLen">The old length.</param>
/// <param name="newp">The newp.</param>
/// <param name="newlen">The newlen.</param>
/// <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
[DllImport(Constants.SystemLibrary)]
internal static extern int sysctlbyname(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string property,
IntPtr output,
IntPtr oldLen,
IntPtr newp,
uint newlen);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the screen diagonal by getting  the phone model accord to judging the screen size of the device . Try to use the following code.

```
CGSize screenSize = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size;
float screenInch;

 // if device is iPhone
 if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
    {
      if(screenSize.Height==812)//iPnone X
        {
          screenInch = 5.8f;
        }

      else if (screenSize.Height == 736) //iPhone 6p 7p 8p
        {
          screenInch = 5.5f;
        }

      else if (screenSize.Height == 667)//iPhone 6 7 8
        {
          screenInch = 4.7f;
        }

      else if (screenSize.Height == 568) // iPhone 5 5s 5c se
        {
           screenInch = 4.0f;
        }

       else //iPhone 4s and before
        {
           screenInch = 3.5f;
        }

     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @LucasZ. That is definitely an option but... i was prevented from using it due to the case of iPad mini and iPad Air: they both have the same height (1024) and the same scale (2x), but since the PPI are different it turns out that they are 7.9 in and 9.7 in respectively...