# Xamarin.Forms FlexLayout resize to a max value

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a **FlexLayout** inside my Xamarin.Forms Application which displays some Frames. The problem is, that if i set `FlexLayout.Grow="1"`, the last frames not completly filling a column will grow to the size where they fill it. But if I set `FlexLayout.Grow="0"` there will be some empty space at the end of each colum.

[image: A simple example]

As you can see under **Allergens** there is a little space at the end of each column which will grow when resizing the Window until a fifth item will fit into the column (when `FlexLayout.Grow="0"` set). But if I set `FlexLayout.Grow="1"` will resize to fil the entire column space until a fifth item will fit into the column. Then all items will resize to their minimum. This is what it should be, BUT I don't want the last items to grow infinitly. See this image:

[image]

Here is the code for the FlexLayout:

```
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="11">
                    <flexLayouts:ExtendedFlexLayout Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                                    Direction="Row"
                                                    Wrap="Wrap"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                                    AlignItems="Start"
                                                    JustifyContent="Start"
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Allergens}">
                        <flexLayouts:ExtendedFlexLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <details:BeverageDetailsView FlexLayout.Grow="1" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </flexLayouts:ExtendedFlexLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </flexLayouts:ExtendedFlexLayout>
                </StackLayout>
```

Is there a way to stop the remaining items from resizing to that big ones?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I think the length of right empty space depending on your `widthRequest` of item.And the `widthRequest` will be calculated by the screen width and margin of boxView.

For example, if you want put 4 items in a row and the boxMargin here is 10.

You should first get screen width, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/26504582/283974

And then, you can calculate the widthRequest of items.

Because there are 4 items in a row, each item has a left and right margin,so there is 8 margins in a row. So the `screenWidth` should minus `itemsInRow *2 * margin`.

```
  float screenWidth = 375;//375 is an example ,you should use screen width in your code
  float margin = 10;
  float itemsInRow = 4;
  float widthRequest = (screenWidth - itemsInRow *2 * margin)/4;
```

Set the `widthRequest` to the item in `Xaml`, then the length of left space and right space will become same.

I add a image here to make it clear:

[image: widthRequest]

Comment: But I don't want the items to be centered, I want them ALL to grow, but none of them should be bigger than an other

Comment: I get a little confused.I think if the items all grow and have the same size in the view,they should look like centered in the view.

Comment: They grow the same size except the ones which cannot fill an entire column. Lets say there are 11 items and column 1, 2 and 3 each contain 3 items which will all have the same size then. So there are 2 items left which will be displayed in column 4, but because there are only 2 (and the other columns contains 3) the 2 items will be way bigger to fill the entire space in column 4. This is not what I need, ALL items should be sized equally

Comment: @Daniel DirtyNative Martin I just edited my answer and reply me if you have any question.

Comment: I really don't like this solution, cause it results in flickering of the items. Is there no built-in way to achieve this?

Comment: No,I tried set all properties of `Flexlayout` differently but I can't achieve it. As I said before, the length of right space is depending on item width.And what is `flickering` caused by?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183270/discussion-between-jack-hua-and-daniel-dirtynative-martin).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a template selector and adding a couple null items to the end of the collection.  The template selector selects the regular template for the display items, and a template with an empty grid for null items.  I created the collection in my view model by wrapping the observable collection and having my view model collection always present N more items as null values.